# Eliminar un documento embebido en mongoDB

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

Tengo esta collecion llamada "Groups" y dentro guardo tareas dentro de un arreglo, estas tareas pertenecen a otra collecion llamada "Tasks", como puedo eliminar una Tarea dentro de mi collecion grupos sin eliminarla de la coleccion Tareas, es decir eliminar por ejemplo la primera tarea dentro del Array "TASKS" de la collecion Groups pero no eliminarla de la collecion "Tasks" en donde esta almacenada tambien

```
[
  {
       "tasks": [
             {
               "id": ""5f4fd82e29444e048c3c4fb",
               "titulo": "Tarea 1",
               "descripcion: "descripcion tarea 1"

             },
            {
               "id": ""344fasd29444e04fsa4fz",
               "titulo": "Tarea 2",
               "descripcion: "descripcion tarea 2"

             }  
       ],
       "id:"5f4faddf87fad4139490157e",
        "nombreGrupo": "grupo 1", 
        "descripcionGrupo": "descripcion grupo 1",

  }
]
```

Como puedo eliminar

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que hayas intentado, aunque esté mal, y el mensaje de error o el comportamiento actual de tu intento. Puedes leer [ask] y [mcve]. La idea es que muestres un ejemplo de lo que has tratado de hacer. Si no has intentado nada, te sugiero que te dirijas a la documentación de MongoDB, donde conseguirás la información que necesitas para resolver tu problema. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una de las cosas más potentes de MongoDB es la capacidad de crecimiento de sus documentos, lo cual permite ir añadiendo campos con diferentes valores atendiendo a las necesidades que nos vayan apareciendo. Pero de igual manera puede aparecer la necesidad de tener que eliminar campo de un documento en MongoDB, ya sea de un documento en concreto o de toda la colección.

Vamos a ver qué pasos necesitaríamos para poder eliminar campo de un documento en MongoDB. Lo primero será conectarnos a nuestra base de datos:

```
conn = new Mongo();
db = conn.getDB("demografia");
```

En concreto nos hemos conectado a una base de datos MongoDB con información demográfica: ciudades, estados,… En el caso de las ciudades los documentos tienen una estructura de esta forma:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("525ab02733b01a66a9dcbc5f"),
    "ciudad" : "Zaragoza",
    "habitantes" : 679624,
    "catedrales" : 2
}
```

El siguiente paso será eliminar el campo «catedrales» del documento, en concreto del documento cuya ciudad coincida con Zaragoza. Para ello vamos a utilizar el operado $unset, dicho operador recibe como parámetro un documento JSON con los campos que queremos borrar.

La sentencia a ejecutar dentro de nuestro Shell de MongoDB será:

```
db.ciudades.update({"ciudad":"Zaragoza"},{$unset:{"catedrales":""}})
```

Vemos que los campos tienen como valor las dobles comillas. Si ahora volvemos a consultar la colección de ciudades veremos que ya no existe el campo catedrales dentro del documento.

```
documento = db.ciudades.findOne({ciudad:"Zaragoza"});
printjson(documento);
```

El operador $unset nos permite de forma sencilla eliminar campo de un documento en MongoDB.

Enlace : http://lineadecodigo.com/mongodb/eliminar-campo-de-un-documento-en-mongodb/

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero el OP no ha mostrado que haya intentado algo. Debemos evitar responder preguntas que no demuestran un clara intención de resolver el problema o que no demuestren que han realizado el esfuerzo de investigar en la documentación oficial la solución que buscan. Saludos

Comment: vale pero mostró un poco de código eso no es valido?

Comment: No, no mostró nada que se considere un intento. Lo único que veo es un `Array` de objetos, presumiblemente de una colección de MongoDB. Eso no es un intento. Las preguntas que piden ayuda con depuración de código deberían mostrar un [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: a pues lo siento no volverá a pasar